# How do I set background, text color and corners on click state of button?

Tags: android, layout, android-button

Here is my `action_btn_state` drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"
    android:color="@color/white">
    <shape>
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/action_btn_border" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>

</item>

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"
    android:color="@color/white">
    <shape>
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/action_btn_border" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:drawable="@null"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent" >
    <shape>
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/action_btn_border" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>

</item>
```

This is my layout

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="70sp"
            android:layout_height="30sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8sp"
            android:padding="0sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/msg_item_action_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/action_btn_state"
            android:text="Like"/>
```

And here is my output, I have taken the screenshot when first button is clicked.As you can see it has no round corners, color is not changed to white and and the default shadow is coming which I dont want. Can anyone help how can I achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use a selector for different states of your button like pressed, focused,... states in separate xml file and set it for your background button
Here is a sample code for selector of a button:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/action_btn_state" />
   <item android:state_pressed="true"android:drawable="@drawable/action_selected"/>
</selector>
```

You can define another xml file for pressed state with your round and color and set in this selector.